# If $S_1$ is orientable and $S_2$ it isn't,

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two closed surfaces. Demonstrate that the following conditions are necessary for there to be a $k$-sheeted covering $p: S_1 \rightarrow S_2 $.

a) $\chi(S_1)=k \chi (S_2)$.

b) If $S_2$ is orientable then $S_1$ is too.

c) If $S_1$ is orientable and $S_2$ isn't, then $k$ is even.

Comment: @PaulVanKoughnett I start to study algebraic topology a few time ago, so I don't have ideas how to do this...

Comment: Well, what do you know?  What definition of the Euler characteristic are you familiar with?  Do you know the correspondence between covering spaces and subgroups of the fundamental group?  Do you know what homology is?  It'd be easier for us to give you hints if we knew where to start from.  (PS: if it helps, part (b) was wrong and I edited it to what I assume is the correct statement.)

Comment: @PaulVanKoughnett For me, is familiar a descomposition of a figure through triangles (I don't know if I explain). I don't know the correspondence between covering spaces and subgroups of the fundamental group. I don't know what is homology. I know something about fundamental group, homotopy, lifiting and I know a few about covering spaces.

Comment: Does the phrase "orientation double cover" ring a bell?